# vCenter migration from one ESXI to another

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I have two ESXI servers, and one VCenter Server appliance on one of those ESXI servers. Now, I want to migrate this VCenter to the other ESXI server because of memory issues. I have multiple virtual machines on one ESXI server which is decreasing the performance of the ESXI so I need to migrate the VCenter server to the other ESXI. Secondly, I do not have a VMFS or a NFS storage nor do I have vMotion, I cannot do those because of iSCSI issues. Is there anyway I could still migrate or should I just make a new vCenter Server for the other ESXI?

Comment: Shut down the vCenter Server and copy the files from one host datastore to the other. Remove it from the inventory on the first host and add it to the inventory on the second host.

Comment: Enabling the SSH service (along with the incoming and outgoing SSH firewall rules) beforehand is useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate a vSphere server without vMotion](https://serverfault.com/questions/407286/migrate-a-vsphere-server-without-vmotion)

Comment: Use following guides to manually migrate vCenter. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004625 
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/16243-how-to-migrate-vcenter-vm-to-a-different-datastore-without-vmotion